# return and yield TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, return, yield

I'm new to Python.
Here is a simple code I wrote to print `x^3`

```
def f(n):
    for x in range(n):
        yield x**3
for x in f(5):
    print x
```

Which print  correct answer.

```
def f(n):
    return [x**3 for x in range(n)]
for x in f(5):
    print x
```

which also print correct answer

```
def f(n):
    for x in range(n):
        return x**3
for x in f(5):
    print x
```

which I got an

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

So what's wrong with the third piece of code.

Comment: `f(5)` returns an integer

Comment: for your third one `f` returns an int ONCE (the first iteration) (reminder that calling `return` will immediately exit a method)

Comment: your other two functions return a i. iterator and a ii. list

Comment: Thanks R Nar. That's exactly what I want to understand.

Answer (score 3):

```
def f(n):
    for x in range(n):
        yield x**3
for x in f(5):
    print x
```

Using `return x**3` will return an int, which is not iterable and hence can't be used with `for`

Answer (score 1):

The 3rd code that you have written for function f(n):

actually returns an integer.

Which as the error suggest is not iterable.

A simple way to test this is open python shell

and copy your code

```
def f(n):
    for x in range(n):
        return x**3

f(5)
```

output:

```
0
```

and 0 is not iterable. so the error message.

to make it work simply change the method to return an array or any iterable object.

```
def f(n):
    for x in range(n):
        return [x**3]

f(5)
```

output :

```
[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a few problems here, if I understand what you're getting at.

(1) There is no reason to use a loop when you're cubing something in the way you're doing it.

```
def cube(n):
    return n**3
```

(2) To print the output, you just need to print it, you don't need to loop.

```
print cube(5)
```

(3) If you want to print a list of cubes.

```
for x in xrange(5):
    print cube(x)
```

(4) You probably don't want to use yield, as it [returns a generator object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python), which it doesn't seem like is what you want here.

Answer (score 0):

```
def f(n):
    for x in range(n):
        return x**3
```

This function return an integer instead of a list

f(5) will be equal to 0^3 (Loop will exit in first iteration itself) , as you can see it is an integer and 
hence can not be iterated.

Comment: This is wrong. f(5) will be equal to 0^3 and will return 0.

Comment: yes Vikash , you are right, it will only be 0^3 since during first iteration loop will exit as soon as it obtain return , i am changing the solution based on your feedback, thanks for pointing out